# JSP page as text in browser

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I reading Spring in Action and trying to repeat code from book. Its work fine when i use html instead of jsp. But problem is that, when i start server, then i see source code of jsp insted of web-page.
My source code is:

WebConfig

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "spittr.web")
public class WebConfig
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

RootConfig

```
    package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr"},
        excludeFilters={
                @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
        })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

SpittrWebAppInitializer

```
    package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

Application

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Created by vadim on 10/5/16.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
package spittr.web;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Structure of project is [image structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynkph.png)

Comment: Remove `SpittrWebAppInitializer`, remove `RootConfig` and remove `WebConfig`. Add `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` to your `application.properties`. Move `Application` to `spittr`. Make sure your packaging is `war` and not `jar`. Run your application. Or stop using Spring Boot and actually follow Spring in Action (which doesn't use Spring Boot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. To run my program just need to detete Application and run program with TomCat(with exploded artifact).